# Ref issue using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a form validation with `react-hook-form` in my current project. I've already tried different approaches but always I got errors because of the `ref` attribute. If I change the `<FormField>` to `input`, it starts to work.
Any idea how to solve this?

**Contact**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import FormField from '../../components/FormField';
import Button from '../../components/Button';

const Contact = () => {
    const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = values => console.log(values);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <FormField
                name="email"
                onChange={() => { console.log("changed!") }}
                ref={register({
                    required: "Required",
                    pattern: {
                        value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                        message: "invalid email address"
                    }
                })}
            />
            <p style={{ color: "red" }}>
                {errors.email && errors.email.message}
            </p>


            <Button>Submit</Button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Contact;
```

**FormField**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";


const FormFieldWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  textarea {
    min-height: 150px;
  }
  input[type="color"] {
    padding-left: 67px;
  }
`;

const Label = styled.label``;

Label.Text = styled.span`
  color: #e5e5e5;
  height: 57px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 16px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;

  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  background: #53585d;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 57px;
  font-size: 18px;

  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #53585d;

  padding: 16px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;

  resize: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: border-color 0.3s;

  &:focus {
    border-bottom-color: var(--primary);
  }
  &:focus:not([type="color"]) + ${Label.Text} {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateY(-10px);
  }
  ${({ value }) => {
    const hasValue = value.length > 0;
    return (
      hasValue &&
      css`
        &:not([type="color"]) + ${Label.Text} {
          transform: scale(0.6) translateY(-10px);
        }
      `
    );
  }}
`;

function FormField({ label, type, name, value, onChange, ref }) {
  const isTypeTextArea = type === "textarea";
  const tag = isTypeTextArea ? "textarea" : "input";
  return (
    <FormFieldWrapper>
      <Label>
        <Input
          as={tag}
          type={type}
          value={value}
          name={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          ref={ref}
        />
        <Label.Text>{label}:</Label.Text>
      </Label>
    </FormFieldWrapper>
  );
}

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: "text",
  value: "",
};

FormField.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  ref: PropTypes.func
};

export default FormField;
```

Errors:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Referring to the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Integratinganexistingform) the register should be used as below so we won't get refs issues and also the **register** will change the value inside the input so we don't need to pass a value prop :

Contact :

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import FormField from "../../components/FormField";
import Button from "../../components/Button";

const Contact = () => {
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (values) => console.log("values", values);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <FormField
        name="email"
        onChange={() => {
          console.log("changed!");
        }}
        register={register}
      />
      <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors.email && errors.email.message}</p>

      <Button>Submit</Button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

FormField :

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const FormFieldWrapper = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  textarea {
    min-height: 150px;
  }
  input[type="color"] {
    padding-left: 67px;
  }
`;

const Label = styled.label``;

Label.Text = styled.span`
  color: #e5e5e5;
  height: 57px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 16px;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;

  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
`;

const Input = styled.input`
  background: #53585d;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 57px;
  font-size: 18px;

  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #53585d;

  padding: 16px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;

  resize: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: border-color 0.3s;

  &:focus {
    border-bottom-color: var(--primary);
  }
  &:focus:not([type="color"]) + ${Label.Text} {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateY(-10px);
  }
  ${({ value = {} }) => { // here you should find an other approch because there is no value props
    const hasValue = value.length > 0;
    return (
      hasValue &&
      css`
        &:not([type="color"]) + ${Label.Text} {
          transform: scale(0.6) translateY(-10px);
        }
      `
    );
  }}
`;

const FormField = ({ label, type, name, onChange, register }) => {
  const isTypeTextArea = type === "textarea";
  const tag = isTypeTextArea ? "textarea" : "input";
  return (
    <FormFieldWrapper>
      <Label>
        <Input
          as={tag}
          type={type}
          //   value={value} it's not a controlled input! so the register'ill provide the value
          name={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          ref={register({
            required: "Required",
            pattern: {
              value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
              message: "invalid email address",
            },
          })}
        />
        <Label.Text>{label}:</Label.Text>
      </Label>
    </FormFieldWrapper>
  );
};

FormField.defaultProps = {
  type: "text",
  value: "",
};

FormField.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  value: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  ref: PropTypes.func,
};

export default FormField;
```